# How to build Rust examples without running

Tags: rust, travis-ci, rust-cargo

Is there any way to build Rust examples without running them?
Specifically to test examples build successfully using Travis CI.

Comment: Could you clarify second sentence a bit? `cargo build` just builds a Rust example. `cargo test` will build and test the cargo. Only `cargo run <name>` will actually run the example?

Comment: @DanielFath I want to test that all the examples actually build without having to run them - `cargo build` runs successfully but when you look in the `...target/debug/examples` directory nothing exists, but if use `cargo run --example <name>` the example is built in that directory?

Comment: Why is that so important? What are you trying to achieve? If your Travis CI runs `cargo test` `cargo build` it will only pass if the both are successfully built.

Comment: have you tried `cargo test examples`? cargo can run specific tests and skip all the others if you pass the name. Maybe that works for examples, too, as long as you do not have any tests named `examples`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cargo test` automatically builds examples (but doesn't run them). I believe it does this first, before the main test runners, but you can verify with `cargo test -v`.

Comment: Nothing seems to be built after running this in the `...target/debug/examples` directory?

Comment: Still need that `carbo build --example <blah>`

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña I am on the latest Nightly and that gives me
`Unknown flag: '--example'

Usage:
    cargo build [options]
`

Comment: @RossMuir my comment was directed at huon. There's currently no way to do what you want aside from what huon suggested, which ends up running the tests. My point is we need something like `cargo build --example <blah>`

Comment: @RossMuir, hm, I'm confused. I just ran `cargo clean && cargo test -v` in one of my own projects, and the output included ``Running `rustc examples/...` `` lines (i.e. building the examples) and `target/debug/examples/` contains all the binaries I would expect. Could you clarify?

Comment: @huon-dbaupp thanks for your help I had `test = false` set for examples in the `cargo.toml` file - setting this to true builds the examples with `cargo test`

Comment: @RossMuir, great! (I believe that `test = true` is the default btw, so you can probably omit it entirely.)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to run with Travis

```
language: rust
rust:
  - stable
  - beta
script:
  - cargo build --verbose --all
  - cargo test --verbose --all
```

Answer (score 0):

`cargo test` runs examples.

To build them it I do this:

```sh
for i in examples/*; do cargo build --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --verbose --example $(basename $i .rs); done
```

[Cargo issue #192](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/192) covers a feature request for something similar.