# How do I run a project's example using Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to run the example code [from this project](https://github.com/basiliscos/rust-procol-ftp-client). Following the instructions on the Cargo docs, I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/basiliscos/rust-procol-ftp-client
cd rust-procol-ftp-client
cargo run 
cargo test
```

`cargo test` should also have compiled [the example](https://github.com/basiliscos/rust-procol-ftp-client/blob/master/examples/ftp-get.rs) according to the Rust docs.

Although `cargo test` executes successfully, when I change into the `target/debug` directory, I don't find an executable for `ftp-get` (which is the example code). The `target/debug/examples` directory is also empty.

What is the best way to go about running this example?

Comment: See also [How to build Rust examples without running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29969208/155423).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cd rust-procol-ftp-client
cargo build --examples
./target/debug/examples/ftp-get
```

Answer (score 40):

You can run a specific example with:

```
cargo run --example name_of_example
```

where `name_of_example` is the base filename (without `.rs`)

or to run it in release mode:

```
cargo run --release --example name_of_example
```

To pass arguments to the example:

```
cargo run --example name_of_example -- arguments go here
```

`cargo run` will automatically build (or rebuild) the program first if it's out of date.